# Suppose $f\in C^1[0,+\infty) $ ,$f(0)=1$ ,$f'(x)=\frac{1}{x^2+f(x)} $

Tags: calculus

Suppose $f\in C^1[0,+\infty) $ ,$f(0)=1$ ,$f'(x)=\frac{1}{x^2+f(x)} $
Proof

1. $\lim_{x\to +\infty }f(x)$ exsits
2. $\lim_{x\to +\infty }f(x)\le1+\frac{\pi}{2} $

All I attempted is connected it to Cauchy Criterion since we just need to proof it exists, but I have no clue for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, $f'(x)>0$ and hence $f(x)$ is increasing in $[0,\infty)$. Second
$$ f'(x)=\frac{1}{x^2+f(x)}\le\frac{1}{x^2+f(0)}=\frac{1}{x^2+1} $$
and so
$$ f(x)-f(0)\le \int_0^x\frac{1}{t^2+1}dt\le\int_0^\infty\frac{1}{t^2+1}dt=\frac{\pi}{2} $$
Namely $f(x)\le1+\frac{\pi}{2}$ or $f(x)$ is bounded in $[0,\infty)$ and hence
$\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)$ exists.

Comment: Can you show strict proof for $f'(x) \gt 0$, I agree with this statement since $f(0)=1$ implies $f'(0)\gt 0$ then $f(x)$ is increasing in a small field around 0.But how to extend this to the interval $[0,+\infty) $. TKS

Comment: @JaqenChou, $f'(x)=\frac{1}{x^2+f(x)}$ can't be zero since the numerator is 1.

Answer (score 0):

Sketch: Suppose you can show $f>0$ everywhere; I'll leave this part to you. Then $f'>0,$ which implies $f$ is strictly increasing. Thus

$$f(x)-f(0) = \int_0^x f'(t)\,dt = \int_0^x \frac{1}{t^2 +f(t)}\,dt \le \int_0^x \frac{1}{t^2 +1}\,dt = \arctan x\le \frac{\pi}{2}.$$

This implies $f$ is bounded above, and since $f$ is strictly increasing, it has a limit at $\infty.$ The bound on the limit follows easily.

Comment: All I have thought is that firstly we can get $f'(x)\gt 0$, then $f(x)\gt 0$. But how can we directly get $f\gt 0$. I can imagine that , but can't proof that with words...

Comment: Perhaps xpaul's reasoning is easier: $x^2+f(x)$ can never equal $0,$ otherwise $f'(x)$ would be undefined at some points. By continuity, $x^2+f(x)$ is then always positive or always negative. Since it's positive at $0,$ it must always be positive.

Answer (score 0):

You can show that $f$ has non-negative derivative. Then  $f(0)=1$ implies that $f$ is nondecreasing and $f\ge 1$. Hence 2 implies 1. To prove 2 compute $$
|f(x)|=|1+\int_0^x \frac1{y^2+f(y)}\,dy|\le 1+\int_0^\infty \frac1{y^2+1}\,dy=1+\pi/2.
$$